# How can I generate a makefile for my project from within Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I need to be able to produce the makefile for my C++ project, although I cannot find how to do this within visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The common solution to this type of problem is to use a cross-platform build system that can generate platform appropriate build files.  CMake is one example of this.  It can be used to generate Solution and Project files on Windows and make files for Linux.  It can also generate make files for mingw32.  Note that this will be a fairly significant departure from your current set up and can take some time to get working correctly.